# How is $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$ continous at $3\pi/2$ when there is a jump continuity to it?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, continuity, graphing-functions

My book says that $f(x) =\lfloor \sin x\rfloor$ is continuous at $3\pi/2$, but on drawing the graph of $\lfloor \sin x\rfloor$, there was a jump continuity at all values of $x$ where $y=1$ or $-1$.

[image: The graph I have drawn.]

The discontinuity is not removable, so how is the function continuous at $3\pi/2$?

Am I wrong somewhere?

---

(**Editor's Note.** I have replaced the original usage of "$[\;\;]$" to denote the "greatest integer function" with the unambiguous "$\lfloor\;\;\rfloor$". —@Blue)

Comment: To be clear: How is "$[\;\;]$" being used here?

Comment: you may drawn wrong graph...

Comment: $f(x)=-1$ in a neighborhood of $3\pi /2$ so it is continuous at $3\pi /2$.

Comment: To pile on with what Blue mentioned - the function $f(x) = [\sin(x)]$ can be taken as "$\sin(x)$ rounded to the nearest integer." If you just mean it as parentheses or whatever, I have no clue what's going on, honestly, because $\sin(x)$ is continuous for all $x$, and certainly has no "jump" discontinuities.

Comment: its $-1$ on $(\pi  , 2\pi )$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer it is the greatest integer function. So your former statement was correct.

Comment: @Blue  "[ ]" is the greatest integer function.

Comment: @Alexallee: Thanks for the clarification. (I see that you have noticed the error in your graph.) Just so you know, "$[\;\;]$" is sometimes used for "greatest integer (floor)", "least integer (ceiling)", and/or "closest integer (rounding)" (among other things), so it's necessary to define the symbol whenever it's used, to avoid confusion. Alternatively, modern typesetting gives us "$\lfloor\;\;\rfloor$" for "floor" and "$\lceil\;\;\rceil$" for "ceiling", so that "$[\;\;]$" (when used a step function at all) is typically reserved for "rounding".

Answer (score 3):

As $[\sin(x)]=-1$ on $(\pi , 2\pi)$ so it is continuous at $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: thankyou sir i have drawn the graph wrong

Comment: ok ....you are welcome ....

Answer (score 0):

The function “greatest integer” is not continuous at integers. So if you consider $g(x)=\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$, where $f$ is continuous, then $g$ *may* be not continuous where $f$ takes on an integer value.

However, the fact that $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$ is not continuous at an integer $n$ stems from the fact that $x\mapsto x$ can take on values greater and less than $n$ in *every* neighborhood of $n$.

In your case, there exists a neighborhood of $3\pi/2$ where $x\mapsto\sin x$ only takes on values $\ge\sin(3\pi/2)=-1$ (for the simple reason that $\sin x\ge-1$ for every $x$).

More generally, if $c$ is a local maximum or minimum point for the function $f$ and $f(c)$ is an integer, then $g(x)=\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: Thankyou. I realised i had drawn the graph wrong.